# Continuity of level set of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I have the following problem in my mind.

Let's say we have a continuous function $F$ on a square $S=[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is known that $F([-1,-0.5]\times [-1,1])<0$ and $F([0.5,1]\times[-1,1])>0$. Does there exist a path from the bottom side $\{(x,y):y=-1\}$ to the upper side $\{(x,y):y=1\}$ such that on the path we have $F=0$? If not, any counter-example would be appreciated. Also any sufficient condition can make it work, e.g. differentiablity of $F$? I am aware of that locally one-to-one would be sufficient but I am interested in the case where this condition does not hold.

I am not sure whether my question is specific enough but roughly speaking, the region on the left is negative under $F$ and the region on the right is positive under $F$, is it possible to construct a path from the lower boundary to the upper boundary using the points under $F$ equals $0$? I cannot imagine how this does not hold but I cannot show it either. Any help or ideas is appreciated.

Thank you.

EDITED: The answer using topologically sine curve shows the answer is negative. What about if we allow multiple paths if they are connected in a small neighbourhood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Just make $F$ the signed distance from a topologist sine curve, for example.  And no, $C^1$ (or $C^k$) is not enough, because you can raise $F$ to a suitable odd power.  Of course, if $F\colon[-1,1]\times[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally one-to-one then $F$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it still false if there are some sort of restriction on $F$ regarding oscillation or variation ?

Comment: What do you mean by oscillation or variation for a function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I was think about controlling the oscillation of the function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics) but I am more interested in the case if I allow multiple paths ``sticking together''. Is it still false? I have edited the question.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer!

Comment: @Hayden we can modify this example to require infinitely many paths, so no.  And of course my original $F$ has oscillation $\inf\{\operatorname{diam}F(U): U\ni s\}=0$ for all $s\in S$ by construction.

Comment: @user10354138. Thank you for your answer again!! Can you please show me the example which requires infinitely many paths? I would like to know more.

Comment: Basically you make $F^{-1}(0)$ (rotated) to be a bunch of topologist sine curve on $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the path $p(t):=(2t-1,2t-1)$ for $t \in [0,1]$ and define

$$f(t):= F(p(t)).$$

Then $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=F(-1,-1)<0$ and $f(1)=F(1,1)>0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(t_0)=0$. Hence $f(p(t_0))=0.$

Comment: But I would like the path the be entirely $0$ under $F$.